# How to troubleshoot error when graphing origins and destination data with Python and pygraphistry?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi everybody I am new here, this is my first problem without a solution I could find in stackoverflow.
I'm trying to use the package pygraphistry in python to plot a graph of my origins and destinations data.

Here is the code:

```
graphistry.register(api=3, protocol="https", server="hub.graphistry.com", username="modu", password="graphviz")

g = graphistry.bind(source="CodeO_str", destination="CodeD_str")
g.edges(indiv_worker_df).plot()
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-1fea7ba5de27> in <module>
      1 g = graphistry.bind(source="CodeO_str", destination="CodeD_str")
----> 2 g.edges(indiv_worker_df).plot()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\graphistry\plotter.py in plot(self, graph, nodes, name, description, render, skip_upload, as_files, memoize)
   1024         elif api_version == 3:
   1025             PyGraphistry.refresh()
-> 1026             dataset = self._plot_dispatch(g, n, name, description, 'arrow', self._style, memoize)
   1027             if skip_upload:
   1028                 return dataset

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\graphistry\plotter.py in _plot_dispatch(self, graph, nodes, name, description, mode, metadata, memoize)
   1178                 or isinstance(graph, pa.Table) \
   1179                 or ( not (maybe_cudf is None) and isinstance(graph, maybe_cudf.DataFrame) ):
-> 1180             return self._make_dataset(graph, nodes, name, description, mode, metadata, memoize)
   1181 
   1182         try:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\graphistry\plotter.py in _make_dataset(self, edges, nodes, name, description, mode, metadata, memoize)
   1447             return self._make_vgraph_dataset(edges_df, nodes_df, name)
   1448         elif mode == 'arrow':
-> 1449             edges_arr = self._table_to_arrow(edges, memoize)
   1450             nodes_arr = self._table_to_arrow(nodes, memoize)
   1451             return self._make_arrow_dataset(edges=edges_arr, nodes=nodes_arr, name=name, description=description, metadata=metadata)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\graphistry\plotter.py in _table_to_arrow(self, table, memoize)
   1379                     1
   1380 
-> 1381             out = pa.Table.from_pandas(table, preserve_index=False).replace_schema_metadata({})
   1382 
   1383             if memoize and (hashed is not None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pandas()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in dataframe_to_arrays(df, schema, preserve_index, nthreads, columns, safe)
    591         for i, maybe_fut in enumerate(arrays):
    592             if isinstance(maybe_fut, futures.Future):
--> 593                 arrays[i] = maybe_fut.result()
    594 
    595     types = [x.type for x in arrays]

~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    426                 raise CancelledError()
    427             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 428                 return self.__get_result()
    429 
    430             self._condition.wait(timeout)

~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py in run(self)
     55 
     56         try:
---> 57             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     58         except BaseException as exc:
     59             self.future.set_exception(exc)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    563             e.args += ("Conversion failed for column {!s} with type {!s}"
    564                        .format(col.name, col.dtype),)
--> 565             raise e
    566         if not field_nullable and result.null_count > 0:
    567             raise ValueError("Field {} was non-nullable but pandas column "

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    557 
    558         try:
--> 559             result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
    560         except (pa.ArrowInvalid,
    561                 pa.ArrowNotImplementedError,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert (0, 52) with type tuple: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type', 'Conversion failed for column edges with type object')
```

I thought the problem was due to the type of my columns that were numeric and I convert them to object but that didn't fix it. How can we do to make the program convert columns into Arrow data type? I would appreciate your help in this one guys, thank you in advance.